# Get sum of values in Foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop that adds all lines from a table with dynamic rows (add row for every new product you want in the order from previous page - sometimes it could be 3 Products, sometimes it could be 23 Products) that creates a pdf purchase order (using mpdf). I'm not having any problem with the line items showing (Product x Quantity = Total) cost for each line. My issue is getting those totals into a single Total cost at the bottom of the Purchase order.

Example on the PDF created:

```
Product 1     $2 x 3 = $6
Product 2     $4 x 2 = $8
Product 3     $6 x 1 = $6
```

All that works correctly. Here is the code for the foreach loop.

```
   <?php

foreach ($product as $a => $b) {

    $prod_cost1[$a] = (("$qty[$a]") * ("$prod_cost[$a]"));

    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$product[$a] &nbsp;</td>
            <td>$qty[$a] &nbsp;</td>
            <td>$prod_cost1[$a] &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>";
}

?>
```

I just somehow need to total all the $prod_cost1 and be able to display that somewhere on the page. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `array_sum($prod_cost1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Just create one more variable before the loop begins and increment it inside the loop.
- **It's a good habit to use proper typecasting when dealing with numbers** (especially in a weakly typed language like PHP). So, I have typecasted the product cost to `float`.

You can use the following code:

```
// Initialize the total sum varaible
$total_sum = 0;

foreach($product as $a => $b) { 

    $prod_cost1[$a] = (("$qty[$a]") * ("$prod_cost[$a]"));

    // update the total sum (typecasting the product cost to float)
    $total_sum += (float)$prod_cost1[$a];

    echo"
         <tr>
         <td>$product[$a] &nbsp;</td>
         <td>$qty[$a] &nbsp;</td>
         <td>$prod_cost1[$a] &nbsp;</td>
         </tr>";
}

// access it
echo $total_sum;
```

Comment: @Psam happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = 0;
foreach($product as $a => $b) { 
    $prod_cost1[$a] = (("$qty[$a]") * ("$prod_cost[$a]"));

    $total += $prod_cost1[$a];

    echo"<tr>
        <td>$product[$a] &nbsp;</td>
        <td>$qty[$a] &nbsp;</td>
        <td>$prod_cost1[$a] &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>";
} 

echo "Total: {$total}";
```

Comment: Not me. But maybe lack of explanation! Also, yours is duplicate of mine :-)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I could say the same thing :) It happens often when racing to get there first.

Comment: @Barry there is a 1 minute gap. Anyways, I agree that you may not have copied my answer.

Comment: @Barry I am upvoting since yours is still a valid answer.

Comment: thanks @MadhurBhaiya I had the same thing earlier... other answer appeared same time as mine 12 votes and accepted... me nothing (at least no down vote)... all because I spent the extra time linking to docs, formatting, etc... which is why I didn't explain here I guess

Comment: @Barry well I know the feeling. Just do your best.. and leave it to SO community's wisdom. In long run, good quality content always wins :)